# Strange JDK behaviour, should it compile?

Tags: generics, compilation, java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main <T> {

    public void guru(List<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println("INteger");
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        new Main().guru(list);
    }
}
```

In my opinion, invoking

```
guru(List<String>); //no type erasure during compiling...
```

should cause compilation to fail.

That's what happens if we create object with:

```
new Main<Integer>() //or any other type
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? That's bug in the JDK or instantiating parametrized object without parameter could cause such problems, and why?

I can add that if we change the Main definition to:

```
public class Main {
```

compilation fails, as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
new Main().guru(list);
       ^^^^
```

You use the raw version of `Main` (without generics) and all generic information is therefore ignored. You should get a compiler warning though.

If you try:

```
new Main<SomeType>().guru(list);
```

You should get a compile error.

More precisely, when using a raw type: `new Main()`, a type erasure is performed, which not only erases generic information from the type itself, but [also from its methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-210):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C [...] is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that raw version means that only that actual parameter is ignored ( in this example <T> ). This explain everything.